# How should I be watching changes to UILabel's text when set in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I'm building a UILabel library that is mostly intended to be used programmatically but I want it to work with Interface Builder as well. When the user calls `setText` on my `UILabel` subclass, I watch it there and update the text as per the label's use, but it doesn't appear to be called with IB.

Should I just be watching `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: Can you post the code where you "watched" it? Usually `viewDidLoad` is where people do that stuff, but `awakeFromNib` would still do the job.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I'm asking where I *would* watch it. :) As it's a `UIView` subclass I have no `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @DougSmith initializer (`initWithCoder:`) should be the right place

Comment: Did the proposed answer work for you? Would you mind editing the title of the question?

Answer (score 0):

## Question should read: Using KVO in UIView subclass

If so, `-initWithCoder:` is the preferred location while `-awakeFromNib` still works as mentioned by @KhanhNguyen.

The problem becomes *How do I find my `UILabel`?* and here is a possible answer using `-viewWithTag:`

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self registerKVO:[self viewWithTag:1]
               forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(text))];
    }
    return self;
}
```

## Answering the general UIViewController question

**Note** *`- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` is not the correct place to install the KVO in a UIViewController since the view hasn't loaded and neither has the label.*

Register KVO using a typical **Referencing Outlet**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self registerKVO:self.label
        forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(text))];
}
```

Regardless of your approach, responding to KVO looks like this:

```
#pragma mark - NSObject(NSKeyValueObserving)

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(text))]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]);
    }
}
```

...and setup + teardown like that:

```
- (void)registerKVO:(NSObject *)object forKeyPath:(NSString *)keypath {
    [object addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:keypath
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:nil];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(text))];
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [super dealloc];
#endif
}
```